# query_posts problem - need help

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I have a taxonomy called `coupon_category`. In a `query_post` I am trying to call all posts from related custom taxonomy with the same `coupon_category`.

If I use:

```
<?php

                    // show all active coupons for this category from related store and setup pagination

                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', 
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => 'mode', 
                            ),
    )
                    ) );                
                ?>
```

I can show all related posts with the term "mode" however I would like to automate it, so that always the terms (`coupon_category`) that are already in use on the page are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a lot of reading I finally changed to 'wp_query' and this is the perfect solution:

```
$tax = get_the_terms($id, 'coupon_category');
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'meta_key' => 'clpr_topcoupon',
                        APP_TAX_TAG => 'gutschein',
                        'orderby'  => array(
                            'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
                            'post_date'      => 'DESC',
                            ),                      
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug, 
                            ),
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term->slug,
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                             ),
                        ),  
                    );
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                        $query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'loop', 'coupon' ); 
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the terms of current post with `get_the_terms` function and then use them in your query.

```
// this will get terms and then get only term_ids from them
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'coupon_category' ), 'term_id' );

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$related = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', 
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term_ids, 
        ),
    )
) );
```

So we use [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to get list of terms for current post and then we call [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck), which is a very handy function, that will get array containing only one field from all of given objects.

PS. I've also changed your `query_posts` to `WP_Query` - it's better for your efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, worked with a little change, now I need to exclude all posts from 'APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,'

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution, quite similar to yours:

```
$tax = get_the_terms($id, 'coupon_category');
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', // Taxonomy
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug, // Your category slug
                            ),
    )

                    ) );
```

Now I only need to exclude post from `APP_TAX_STORE` with current slug or from taxonomy `stores`.

Comment: finale solution see other answer from me!